# Upload artifact to gitlab maven repository

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, gitlab

I tried to used https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html to host my aar file, I followed exact same as the documentations yet I failed to upload the aar. I've setting the pom.xml like this :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.2</version>
    <packaging>aar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>myrepo</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1968/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>myrepo</id>
                       <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1968/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>myrepo</id>
<url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1968/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.greenrobot</groupId>
            <artifactId>eventbus</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>28.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.arch.lifecycle</groupId>
            <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.arch.lifecycle</groupId>
            <artifactId>extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.arch.lifecycle</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.nlopez.smartlocation</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-services-location</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android.arch.lifecycle</groupId>
            <artifactId>livedata</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and as well my `~/.m2/settings.xml` like this :

```html
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>myrepo</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>myprivatetoken</value>
            <scope>api</scope>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

By that I got the following error :

Failed to execute goal on project kudosdk: Could not resolve dependencies for project mobile.kudo.kudosdk:kudosdk:aar:0.1.2: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.android.support:support-v4:pom:28.0.0 ....... and the list goes to all the dependencies who missing pom file. Yet if I remove the dependencies from my pom.xml I got error saying that `error during copyManifest` and point to the location where my manifest exist.

Also if I change the packaging become `pom` it can successfully deployed to my gitlab repository but it only pom file, with no aar file deployed and I am not sure how to fetch the dependencies via gradle. I tried using 
`implementation 'groupid:module:version'` but it failed saying failed to resolved the dependency which means the dependency didn't exist.

any help would be much appreciated, I've been struggle for 4 days try to resolve this. thank you

Comment: First of all you should look at your dependencies and make sure that they are properly resolve.d

Comment: thanks for your response @jf-meier . yes, I looked at ~/.m2/repository and all required dependency already there. also when I change the package become pom, it successfully uploaded but without aar

Comment: So the missing artifact `com.android.support:support-v4:pom:28.0.0` is in your local repository?

Comment: @JFMeier yes, if I open the directory I have these following files support-v4-28.0.0.jar.lastUpdated support-v4-28.0.0.pom.lastUpdated which located in ~/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/28.0.0/

Comment: The "lastUpdated" means that the files are actually missing, and this information is stored for 24 hours. You need to find out why Maven does find the pom, maybe you are missing a repository.

Comment: @JFMeier oh I see, I've added repository for maven google and jcenter, and the previous error gone but I still missed this dependencies com.android.support:support-fragment:jar:26.1.0 . . .

Comment: Thank you @JFMeier for your response, I finally figured this out by using gradle plugin instead of writing pom.xml manually